# Search nested object with spring data, Illegal attempt to dereference path source

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I use spring data jpa, I have these classe (each one have id... not displayed)

```
public class HOV{

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_type_id")
    private VehicleTypes vehicleType;
    ...
}

public class VehicleTypes{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicleType")
    private List<Vehicles> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

so in hov repository, i tried to search by vehiclesId

```
List<HOV> findByVehicleTypeVehiclesId(Integer id);
```

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>   Error creating bean with name 'hOVRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List
>   com.lcm.repository.HOVRepository.findByVehicleTypeVehiclesId(java.lang.Integer)!
>   Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.vehicleType.vehicles]
>   of basic type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I think, is better to provide a query yourself, for example:

```
@Query("select h from HOV h join h.vehicleType vt left join vt.vehicles v where v.id = ?1")
List<HOV> findWithQuery(Integer vehicleId);
```